# Enlace en la misma página jsf / primefaces

Tags: javascript, primefaces

Tengo una tabla y quiero que cuando pulsen en un botón lleve al final de la página.

Tabla:

```
<p:datatable>
  ...
    <p:column style="width:32px;text-align: center">
        <p:commandButton id="btn" update="form" oncomplete="ScrollPage('anchorSecondPanel')"  icon="ui-icon-search" title="View">
       </p:commandButton>
    </p:column>
</p:datatable>
```

Abajo tengo el ancla:

```
<a id="anchorSecondPanel"/>
```

La funcion javascript:

```
function ScrollPage(location) {
    window.location.hash=location;
}
```

El problema es que cuando pulso sobre el botón la primera vez funciona, pero la segunnda ya no dirige a ese ancla.

¿Alguien sabe el motivo?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El problema es que al cambiar el valor del `hash`, funciona la primera vez pero cuando pulsas de nuevo sobre ese botón, el `hash` es el mismo por lo que la URL será la misma y el navegador no hará nada (porque no hay un cambio real a aplicar).

Una solución (no sé si la mejor, pero funcionará) es cambiar el `hash` dos veces: primero a un valor que no exista y luego al valor al que quieres ir. De ese modo, con el primer cambio el navegador *reseteará* el `hash` y con el segundo (que ocurre inmediatamente después) se hará el scroll en sí:

```
function ScrollPage(location) {
  window.location.hash="#";
  window.location.hash=location;
}
```

---

Sin PrimeFaces, pero aquí puedes ver una demo con el código funcionando:

```js
function ScrollPage(location) {
  window.location.hash = "#";
  window.location.hash = location;
}

var botones = document.querySelectorAll("button");
for (var x = 0; x < botones.length; x++) {
  botones[x].addEventListener("click", function() {
    var target = this.dataset.target;
    ScrollPage(target);
  });
}
```

```css
div {
  margin-top: 1000px;
}

div:first-child {
  margin-top: 0;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <button data-target="#a">A</button>
  <button data-target="#b">B</button>
  <button data-target="#c">C</button>
</div>

<div id="a">a</div>
<div id="b">b</div>
<div id="c">c</div>
```